# Has anyone the knowledge of derivation of Hydrogen atom's eigenvalues using real only wave equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

The Quantum theory can be formulated using real numbers , complex numbers and quaternions. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5690) is the link to the paper on arxiv.org. I wish to increase my knowledge on the subject, particularly I want to know how the Hydrogen atom's (or hydrogen like atoms) 'real' wave function is used to derive its eigenvalues.
The real number derivation is expected to give the exact same solution as Schrodinger's complex wave equation.

My question is: Has anyone the knowledge of derivation of Hydrogen atom's eigenvalues using real only wave function?

Comment: If you just superpose the $+m$ and $-m$ wavefunctions, you can make real wavefunctions.

Comment: But that will just give me real and imaginary parts. I want the full derivation if possible. I want to see what assumptions are made for quantizations.

Comment: FWIW, the TISE is real.

Comment: .... and you may wish to look at the [Madelung Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_equations), which is another equivalent formulation of Schrödinger's equation